Efficiently look up a column value in a column containing lists with pandas
Assuming the following pandas data frame:
                                   data  lookup_val
0       [1.3, 4.5, 6.4, 7.3, 8.9, 10.3]           5
1  [2.5, 4.7, 6.4, 6.6, 8.5, 9.3, 17.4]           3
2       [3.3, 4.2, 5.1, 7.8, 9.2, 11.5]           6

I need to look up the value within the list of each 'data' column at the position of the value in the 'lookup_val' column.
Expected output would be a new column like this:
                                   data  lookup_val  output
0       [1.3, 4.5, 6.4, 7.3, 8.9, 10.3]           5     8.9
1  [2.5, 4.7, 6.4, 6.6, 8.5, 9.3, 17.4]           3     6.4
2       [3.3, 4.2, 5.1, 7.8, 9.2, 11.5]           6    11.5

What is the most efficient way to do so, assuming the data frame has millions of rows like this with each list having a different length, but no longer than 50 values?
Iterating over the data frame or using apply with a simple indexing takes literally hours and a more performant structure is needed.
Code to generate the above sample:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'data': [1.3, 4.5, 6.4, 7.3, 8.9, 10.3], 'lookup_val': 5},
        {'data': [2.5, 4.7, 6.4, 6.6, 8.5, 9.3, 17.4], 'lookup_val': 3},
        {'data': [3.3, 4.2, 5.1, 7.8, 9.2, 11.5], 'lookup_val': 6},
    ]
)


There is no efficient vectorial way to perform this. You need to loop. The easiest is most likely to use a list comprehension and zip:
df['output'] = [l[i-1] for l, i in zip(df['data'], df['lookup_val'])]

Since your lookup values use a one-based indexing, you must subtract 1.
Output:
                                   data  lookup_val  output
0       [1.3, 4.5, 6.4, 7.3, 8.9, 10.3]           5     8.9
1  [2.5, 4.7, 6.4, 6.6, 8.5, 9.3, 17.4]           3     6.4
2       [3.3, 4.2, 5.1, 7.8, 9.2, 11.5]           6    11.5

If there is a chance that lookup values are incorrect, you should add a manual check. For example checking for the upper bound:
df['output'] = [l[i-1] if i<= len(l) else None
                for l, i in zip(df['data'], df['lookup_val'])]

Or with a custom function:
def get_val(lst, i):
    try:
        return lst[i-1]
    except IndexError:
        return None

df['output'] = [get_val(*x) for x in zip(df['data'], df['lookup_val'])]

Output:
                                   data  lookup_val  output
0       [1.3, 4.5, 6.4, 7.3, 8.9, 10.3]           5     8.9
1  [2.5, 4.7, 6.4, 6.6, 8.5, 9.3, 17.4]           3     6.4
2       [3.3, 4.2, 5.1, 7.8, 9.2, 11.5]           7     NaN

timings
Using up to 1M rows with a random number of items in each list between 1 and 50:

Code to set up the random example:
def init(N):
    ns = np.random.randint(1, 51, size=N)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [list(range(n)) for n in ns]})
    df['lookup_val'] = np.random.randint(0, ns, size=N)
    return df

I also tested the implication of incorrect values for the custom function. For this I generated a second lookup column with 90% chance that the value in out of bounds. This seems to have a limited impact on efficiency (the other two approaches still use a valid lookup value in this graph):


Your speed is crazy, answered in ~1min ;)

@Timeless the question appeared right when I was reading the new questions ;)

The speed was indeed incredible, I was just looking away for a second and thought the "1 new answer" must be some kind of auto-message ;) Thanks! Very unfortunate there is no vectorial way, I was hoping for that. However, your list comprehension is still way faster than whatever mess I created earlier in my lambdas. So this might still work fine for my use case or else I have to review my pre-processing leading me to a case requiring calculations at that scale incompatible with vectorial calculations.

Minor addition: I changed if i<= len(l) else None to if l and i and i<= len(l) else None because 'data' may contain empty lists and 'lookup_val' may be 0. But I failed to mention this in my example as well as the question itself, so the given answer is perfectly correct the way it is.

@Cerealz I also added a more generic option with a custom function

My proposition is to use indexing from numpy :
N = 1 # index' base

df["output"] = (
    pd.DataFrame(df["data"].tolist()).to_numpy()[
        np.arange(len(df)), df["lookup_val"].sub(N)
    ]
)

Output :
                                   data  lookup_val  output
0       [1.3, 4.5, 6.4, 7.3, 8.9, 10.3]           5     8.9
1  [2.5, 4.7, 6.4, 6.6, 8.5, 9.3, 17.4]           3     6.4
2       [3.3, 4.2, 5.1, 7.8, 9.2, 11.5]           6    11.5


One drawback of this approach to keep in mind is that it creates a large intermediate. If you have one list with a huge number of items, then this will create an rectangular intermediate with lots of NaNs.

I feel like your approach is better/faster. It would be great if you could whip up one of your beautiful perfplots. OP mentions "the dataframe has millions of rows... each list having a different length, but no longer than 50 values".

of course, see update

I was literally typing code to do this in right this minute and you outpaced me. Thanks again! I assume it's time to mark mozway's answer as accepted to close this question.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {'data': [[1.3, 2.5, 3.4, 4.3, 5.9, 6.3],
                 [1.5, 2.7, 3.4, 4.6, 5.5, 6.3, 7.4],
                 [1.3, 2.2, 3.1, 4.8, 5.2, 6.5]],
        'lookup_val': [5, 3, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
flattened_data = np.concatenate(df['data'].values)
lookup_indices = np.concatenate(([0],np.cumsum([len(lst) for lst in df['data']][:-1])) )
print(lookup_indices )#[ 0  6 13]
positions = lookup_indices + (df['lookup_val'].values -1)
print(positions)#[ 4  8 18]
res = flattened_data[positions]
df['res'] = res
print(df)
'''
                                 data  lookup_val  res
0       [1.3, 2.5, 3.4, 4.3, 5.9, 6.3]           5  5.9
1  [1.5, 2.7, 3.4, 4.6, 5.5, 6.3, 7.4]           3  3.4
2       [1.3, 2.2, 3.1, 4.8, 5.2, 6.5]           6  6.5
'''

For Huge and Sparse datasets, Use: csr_matrix
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix


data = {'data': [[1.3, 2.5, 3.4, 4.3, 5.9, 6.3],
                 [1.5, 2.7, 3.4, 4.6, 5.5, 6.3, 7.4],
                 [1.3, 2.2, 3.1, 4.8, 5.2, 6.5]],
        'lookup_val': [5, 3, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Get the number of rows in the DataFrame
num_rows = len(df)

# Combine all elements from the lists into a single flat array
flattened_data = np.concatenate(df['data'].values)

# Calculate starting positions for each sublist (original list) within the flattened array
lookup_indices = np.concatenate(([0], np.cumsum([len(lst) for lst in df['data']][:-1])))

# Create a helper array to represent row indices for the CSR matrix
row_indices = np.repeat(np.arange(num_rows), [len(lst) for lst in df['data']])

# Create another helper array to represent column indices for the CSR matrix
col_indices = np.concatenate([np.arange(len(lst)) for lst in df['data']])

# Build the CSR matrix using flattened data, row and column indices, and define its shape
sparse_matrix = csr_matrix((flattened_data, (row_indices, col_indices)), 
                           shape=(num_rows, np.max([len(lst) for lst in df['data']])))

# Perform the lookups:
#  - Combine starting positions with lookup values minus 1 for zero-based indexing
#  - Access corresponding elements from the CSR matrix
#  - Convert the sparse matrix result to a regular NumPy array
positions = lookup_indices + (df['lookup_val'].values - 1)
res = sparse_matrix[np.arange(num_rows), df['lookup_val'].values - 1].A.flatten()

# Add the lookup results as a new column named 'res' to the DataFrame
df['res'] = res

print(df)
'''
                                 data  lookup_val  res
0       [1.3, 2.5, 3.4, 4.3, 5.9, 6.3]           5  5.9
1  [1.5, 2.7, 3.4, 4.6, 5.5, 6.3, 7.4]           3  3.4
2       [1.3, 2.2, 3.1, 4.8, 5.2, 6.5]           6  6.5
'''

